# How to split 'Hour' and 'Minute' from my dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have been trying to split 'h' & 'm' from my column data and extract it into another column.

Here is my data:

```
   Duration
   2h 50m
      25m
   19h
```

And this is my code:

```
duration = list(datasets['Duration'])

for i in range(len(duration)):
    if len(duration[i].split()) != 2:
    if 'h' in duration[i]:
        duration[i] = duration[i].strip() + '0m'
    else:
        duration[i] = '0h' + duration[i]
        
   duration_hours = []
   duration_mins = []

   for i in range(len(duration)):
      duration_hours.append(int(duration[i].split(sep = 'h')[0]))
      duration_mins.append(int(duration[i].split(sep = 'm')[0].split()[-1]))
```

I am trying to split hours and minutes and trying to extract it into hours and minutes column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and with accesor [`dt.components`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.components.html):

```
s=pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration'])
df['hours']=s.dt.components['hours']
df['minutes']=s.dt.components['minutes']

print(df)
  Duration  hours  minutes
0   2h 50m     2       50
1      25m     0       25
2      19h    19        0
```

Comment: Hi @MrNobody33, could you explain me the first line of your code?

Comment: Hi! @Raptor795 First line is to convert 'Duration' column to timedelta.  I use dummy series called `s` to preserve the original string format. See the link I attached to see how `to_timedelta` works.

Answer (score 0):

```
if 'h' in duration[i]:
    duration[i] = duration[i].strip() + ' 0m' #----> just add the space here " 0m"
else:
    duration[i] = '0h ' + duration[i] #------> add the space here "0h " as well
```